# How to decrypt a file only if specific conditions are not met

Tags: encryption, protocols

I know how to decrypt a file after one or more specific environnemental conditions are met (with secure triggers).

I am interested in a cryptographic sheme that would enable decryption of data only if specific conditions are not present (only know to the author), eg :

- A specific software is not currently running
- A specific file is not present
- ...

even if it require a lot of computing power, share your ideas

Comment: Im not sure I understand your question, do you mean like an algorithm that only works under certain conditions?

Comment: i want to deliver a payload only when certain conditions are not present, i need something like secure triggers but only when specific conditions are not met for deliver it securely and i want a solution cryptographically secure

Comment: what you're trying to achieve, judging from the (only known to author) part, is something called "security by obscurity" and is far from "cryptographically secure" as it has nothing to do with cryptography. You can't achieve the "conditioning" as long as the conditions are not directly related to the cipher algorithm, such as IV or encryption key. You'll need a hardware component that does such thing, like am HSM or a smartcard.  Perhaps try to rephrase the question, it's quite unclear now.

Comment: I think that he did not mean it as in that being the only measure, but as an additional step. It is much the same way as having second password. You still have to provide the key, but even if you know the passcode, it is not able to recover the information by itself. Two-step authentication is based on the same behavior. It entirely relies on you knowing the password and a second piece of information only disclosed to you. You may program the software to only decode the data if someone provides the correct passkey at a certain location, therefore linking the decryption key to a GPS coordinate.

Comment: GPS coordinates provide an amazing spectrum of possible keys. Don't forget that you also have the altitude variable. You may lock the container to a spatial ordinate/coordinate, therefore demanding the attacker to be at that specific place to be able to be successful. Imagine if you had to be at the middle of the ocean at 500 feet to start typing the password? It obviously can be broken as everything in the virtual field, but it surely provides a good obstacle.

Comment: ... and a virtual GPS receiver provides arrays of coordinates at amazing speeds. So as long as the encrypted system is self-contained and tamper-proof, this doesn't change a thing. Any such measure can be circumvented in similar fashion.