# Ensure that a file can only be decrypted after a specific condition is not present

Tags: encryption, protocols

Are there any cryptographic schemes/protocols that would allow me to encrypt a file, make it publicly available, but ensure that it can only be decrypted when a specific condition is not present (I want to ensure for example that a specific software is not installed when the decrypt of that file occurs) ?

I assume it would be almost impossible without a trusted authority. Or is there some way?

I was inspired by the idea of "secure triggers", which is a scheme to decrypt data after a specific (or a set of) condition(s) is present.

In contrast, I am interested in a cryptographic scheme that would enable decryption of data only if a specific condition is not present on the host computer

Comment: a scheme that can only decrypt if specific information is hidden? AFAIK this is impossible as the system could always hide the information from the protocol / algorithm and hence get the decrypted result even if the object / condition is actually present.

Comment: this is a duplicate of a closed question: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/91063/how-to-decrypt-a-file-only-if-specific-conditions-are-not-met

Comment: As others said in the other question, it's not a matter of the cryptography, but about the software that does the cryptography. At that point, you can use whatever criteria that you want to. Also, it would be helpful if you cited your source for "secure triggers" for us to understand your perspective on the question.